# How to update multiple things in collection in Pymongo?

Tags: python, pygame, pymongo

```
collection.find_one_and_update(
    {'username': hero.name}, {'$set': {'exp': hero.exp}})
collection.find_one_and_update(
    {'username': hero.name}, {'$set': {'level': hero.level}})
```

I have two updates like this. Is there any way to combine them into one?

Comment: `collection.find_one_and_update(
    {'username': hero.name}, {'$set': {'exp': hero.exp, 'level': hero.level}})`

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge the updated values object like so:

```py
collection.find_one_and_update({
    'username': hero.name
}, {
    '$set': {
        'exp': hero.exp, 
        'level': hero.level
}})
```